# Jenkins Multijob - pass project name parameter from Build_job1 to Deploy_job2

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-plugins

on a multi job I have two phases:

1. PhaseA running Build_job1, with a project name Build_job1, pulling stuff from git to dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Build_job1
2. PhaseB running Deploy_job2, that rsyncs /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Build_job1/* to a bunch of servers.

For internal reasons I need to replicate the multijob, the build job and the deploy job to different environments (PROD, QA, Staging). I each case, the deploy job rsync will need to copy files from a different build directory (Build_QA, Build_Prod, Build_whatever etc.).

As Jenkins creates the dir per project name, I need the rsync command in the deploy job to get the project name as a parameter that is passed down from the build job.

help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to pass down the current job's project name down to its children?  If so, you can pass down this information via a [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project) call "JOB_NAME" in conjunction with a predefined job parameter.  For example, something like:

```
Param1=${JOB_NAME}
```

If the Multijob job name is "QA", you can pass that down to both the build and deploy phase jobs via a predefined parameter and then construct the final "*Build_QA*" path by doing something like "*Build_${Param1}*" or "*Build_%Param1%*".